# How to handle objects that dont have a default constructor but are constructed in another constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I have the following sample code

```
class ClassB {
    public:
    ClassB(int i); // No default constructor
}

class ClassA {
    ClassB obj; //NOT a pointer
    public 
    ClassA() {
        //calculate someInt;
        obj = ClassB(someInt); // doesnt work
    }

}
```

How do I initialize `obj`?
The compiler complains about `no appropriate default constructor available` for `obj`

Comment: You can do `ClassA() : obj(someInt) {}`

Answer (score 2):

The best design solution for you would be to initialize member `obj` in the [initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) like this:

```cpp
ClassA() : obj(someInt) { }
```

However, another option for you would be to declare the default constructor for `ClassB` like this:

```cpp
ClassB() {}
```

or simply let the compiler create the one for you by using this:

```cpp
ClassB() = default;
```

From C++ Standard this is:

> defaulted default constructor: the compiler will define the implicit
>   default constructor even if other constructors are present.

If you go for a second option, then the following code would pass without the error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB() = default;
    ClassB(int i);
};

class ClassA {
    ClassB obj;
public: 
    ClassA() {
        int someInt = 0;
        obj = ClassB(someInt);
    }
};

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+ClassB+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++ClassB()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++ClassB(int+i)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+ClassA+%7B%0A++++ClassB+obj%3B%0Apublic:+%0A++++ClassA()+%7B%0A++++++++int+someInt+%3D+0%3B%0A++++++++obj+%3D+ClassB(someInt)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.308093994778076,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.97651026222455,l:'4',m:51.042810098792536,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+9.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.957189901207464,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.691906005221924,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

**Conclusion**

I would deeply recommend using the first option, the one with the initialization list because it is not needed to default construct objects before and then assigning to them. Also, this is the only option for objects that don't have an assignment operator.

**UPDATE 1**

One more way around this problem is using the `std::shared_ptr<ClassB> obj` in your `ClassA` as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB(int i);
};

class ClassA {
    std::shared_ptr<ClassB> obj;
public: 
    ClassA() {
        int someInt = 0;
        obj = std::make_shared<ClassB>(someInt);
    }
};

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

One more possibility that came up to my mind is to calculate integer in a separate function and the just call it as part of the initialization list like in the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB(int i);
};

class ClassA {
    ClassB obj;
public: 
    ClassA()
        : obj(calculate())
    {}

private:
    int calculate() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:23,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:23,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:23,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:23),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+ClassB+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++ClassB(int+i)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+ClassA+%7B%0A++++ClassB+obj%3B%0Apublic:+%0A++++ClassA()%0A++++++++:+obj(calculate())%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%0Aprivate:%0A++++int+calculate()+%7B%0A++++++++return+1%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.308093994778076,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'--std%3Dc%2B%2B2a',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.97651026222455,l:'4',m:51.042810098792536,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.957189901207464,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.691906005221924,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `ClassA() {
        int someInt = 0;
        obj = ClassB(someInt);
    }` . It's always preferable to use the initialization list rather than the constructor body, so you don't needlessly default constructor objects before then assigning to them. It's also the *only* option for objects that don't have an assignment operator.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I agree. That's why I noted that the initialization list is far better option. I will update my answer with this also just to highlight the downside. Tnx

Comment: How do I put things into the initialization List when the parameters for the constructor need to be calculated?
In the example above `someInt` isnt known at compile time

Comment: I am aware of that. That's why I listed second option too. If you want to use initialization list along with calculating the integer value, you would need to change your design a bit. I can't recommend you the best option because I don't know the logic behind calculating the integer value. Another way around would be to use `std::shared_ptr<ClassB> obj` member.

Comment: I am aware that i can avoid this whole problem by using a pointer. but that's exactly not what I want.
The initialization list approach doesnt work, since `someInt` is only known during the constructor of `ClassA`, not before.

Comment: Then use the 2nd option. With `ClassB`'s default constructor but reassigning the object in the `ClassA`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize members in the constructor initialization list. Like so:

```
ClassA() : obj(someInt) { }
```